# Flask: dynamic routing causes render_template to ignore (jinjer2) html-formatting

Tags: html, flask, dynamic, routes

this is my first post on stackoverflow, I usually search to death and find a solution, but this problem I am facing is driving me nuts.

I am taking a web programming course where I have to submit a project (book reviews page). After registering and logging into the website one can search for a book and check its details.

In `search.html` I use `href="{{ url_for('layout_books', isbn=isbn) }}"` which calls a method in my `application.py`.

Here is the `search.html`:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %} Find your Book {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="{{ url_for('get_books') }}" method="post">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
      <small id="username_help" class="form-text text-muted">{{ message }}</small>
  </div>
    <h1>Results:</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for title, author, year, isbn in search_results %}
        <li> <i>Title:</i> <a href="{{ url_for('layout_books', isbn=isbn) }}">{{ title }}</a>,
            <i>Author:</i> {{ author }},
            <i>Year:</i> {{ year }}
            - ISBN {{ isbn }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
        <small style="color:magenta"> {{ result }}</small>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

```py
@app.route("/layout_books/<isbn>")
@project_tools.login_required
def layout_books(isbn):
    # some stuff happens here: getting data from database

    return render_template("layout_books.html",
                           title=title,
                           author=author,
                           year=year,
                           isbn=isbn,
                           review_count=review_count,
                           average_rating=average_score,
                           gr_number_ratings=gr_number_ratings,
                           gr_average_rating=gr_average_rating,
                           message=message,
                           reviews=reviews)
```

So instead of getting this format (myreviews subpage):
[correctly displayed navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPI5E.png)

I get this messed up formatting (layout_books/isbn-number-here): 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUZMU.png)

I guess I am missing some concept, but I could not figure out what it is.

The `layout_books.html` looks like this, but even stripping it down to only the first two lines exposed the same problem:

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %} {{ title }} {% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li>Title: <i>{{ title }}</i></li>
                <li>Author: <i>{{ author }}</i></li>
                <li>Year: <i>{{ year }}</i></li>
                <li>ISBN: <i>{{ isbn }}</i></li>
                <li>Review Count: <b>{{ review_count }}</b></li>
                <li>Average User Rating: <b>{{ average_rating }}</b></li>
                <li>Goodreads Review Count: <b>{{ gr_number_ratings }}</b></li>
                <li>Average Goodreads Rating: <b>{{ gr_average_rating }}</b></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <form action="{{url_for('add_review')}}" method="post">
        <button>Write a book review -></button>
    </form>
    <h3>{{ message }}</h3>
        <div class="container">
            {% for name, title, text, rating in reviews %}
            <ul>
                <li><b>{{ title }}</b> - <small>by {{ name }} </small>Rating: {{ rating }}
                <details>
                    <summary>
                        Collapse for full review.
                    </summary>
                    <p> {{ text }} </p>
                </details>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Edit: added parent template `layout.html`

Here is the parent template `layout.html`. I did not add it earlier because I didn't know it would matter. As it turns out, it did...

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %} Stuff here {% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/navigation_bar.css">
<!--    add this workaround because page is not correctly formatted with dynamic routing. It seems as though in this
        case the import of local css file is ignored. This block is used in layout_books.html-->
        <style>
        {% block style %}
        {% endblock %}
        </style>
<!--    end of workaround    -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <head><h1>{% block head %} {% endblock %}</h1></head>
    <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom shadow fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Book Reviews</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('search') }}">Search</a>
        </li>
          {% if session.get('username') %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('my_reviews') }}">My Reviews</a>
        </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout - {{ session.get('username') }}</a>
        </li>
          {% else %}
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
        </li>
          {% endif %}
          {% if not session.get('username') %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a>
        </li>
          {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, using dynamic routing causes the rendered html to ignore the locally linked css file which I defined in the parent html file `layout.html`. So as a workaround I added a `{% block style %} {% endblock %}` in `<style>`-tags. I had to then copy the content of my local css file into the `style` block. It's pretty ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

In `layout_books.html` you are missing all html tags (that are present in `search.html`).

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %} {{ title }} {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
```

and at the end :

```
</body>
</html>
```

The following link might help you to test your html code :
https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Thank you. I added the tags, without luck. The validator would cut my code and can't validate jinja2 code. And as mentioned in my last sentence, even stripping the html code down to the first 2 lines would not help.

Comment: For the validator link, you have to check the generated html code : open the test website with your favorite web browser then use it to show source code of the page (on Firefox ; right click on the page and source code). And then copy paste it into the validator.